# Markdown & Pandoc : How to include a specific PDF page as image?

Tags: pdf, images, markdown, pandoc

It is currently possible to insert a PDF as an image in markdown files through pandoc by doing this:

```markdown
# Hello World
![My PDF file inserted](my-pdf.pdf)
```

Then you convert that markdown file with pandoc:

```bsh
~$ pandoc -s -f markdown-implicit_figures my-document.md -o my-document.pdf
```

And it works! **But pandoc only inserts the first page** of `my-pdf.pdf`.

Is it possible to set which page to insert, or better, which pages range?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: not really an answer (i don't know if pandoc can do what you want or not), but as a last resort, `pdfseparate` from poppler-utils can split a multi-page PDF into multiple PDF files.   You could then include the specific pages you wanted.

Comment: Absolutely, you can also extract one specific page with `pdftk`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there are only two options:

- Split the pdf in multiple 1-page documents `p1.pdf`, `p2.pdf`, etc., and insert them with

```
![](p1.pdf)
![](p2.pdf)
```

- Use

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{myfile.pdf}
```

But this works only if you output `tex` or `pdf` documents.

You may find this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52486342/2657549) useful.